# Function Echo vs Return

Tags: php, function

Okay, so I have some code that is giving me fits.

To call the function `d($z);`

$z itself is a declared variable elsewhere in the code.

This doesn't work:

```
function d($x1){
$distance = $x1;
return $distance;
}
```

This works:

```
function d($x1){
$distance = $x1;
echo $distance;
}
```

Any ideas why?

Note: I don't want the value echo'd. I want to be able to use the value later on, as a variable, and not necessarily printed to the screen. (Now, the above is a simplified version, a lot has been removed, of what I really want to do, but even the above doesn't return properly for me)

Although it's not what I want to do, since I want to use the result of $distance as an internal variable (not echo it), if I do `<?=$distance?>` it doesn't work with the return.

Comment: Show the code that calls the function. Does it assign the result to a variable?

Comment: How do you call d()? Post the rest of the code.

Comment: Does'nt return properly what ? you have to give us more details. How its being used, etc?

Comment: Posted the call to d().

Comment: Please post a complete example of how your are calling `d()` and why you think the return value is not working. Are you assigning to another variable? echoing?

Comment: Everything has been posted. The call to the function. The function itself. There is nothing left to post. Now, a hint came at a now deleted answer to this question, which makes the following work: `function distance($x1, &$distance = FALSE){
$distance = $x1;
return $distance;
}` Really? No one could tell me that I needed to declare $distance in the function call along with $x1 for it to work? Instead everyone keeps asking me to repost what's already posted. Thanks anyway. If I could select that answer that assisted me, I would. But, as stated, someone deleted the helpful answer.

Comment: @WitoldKowelski - no. Both functions work.  The one that echoes the value, prints it out to the screen. The one that returns a value, returns it - it won't print anything out unless you do something with it. If you're just calling `d($z)`, it will return a value, but since you're not assigning the return value from it, it won't do anything else. You're making this a lot more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: If the question is why $distance isn't useable outside of the function then it's simply because of what's called scope. In other words, the variable ceases to exist as soon as code inside the function has stopped running. If you want $distance to be useable outside of a function (not exactly a good practice...) you could use a global variable. Also, &$distance (notice the ampersand) in the function signature is passing a variable by reference and not value.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible (probably more) problems:

1. You are not passing a correct value into the function

   or
2. You are not assigning the return to a variable (ex. `$value = d("some value here");`)

Edit: Don't forget to echo $value (stored return)

Comment: Weird... when I went to edit, it says 2 (I swear I typed 2), and still outputs 1. What the heck?

Comment: @Barmar he actually wrote it right but forgot to add the space to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

Both are working exactly as expected.

In first example you don't display the value of function d

change it to

```
function d($x1)
{
         $distance = $x1;
         return $distance;
}

echo d(5);
```

and it will display it.

In second case you don't return the value so function is void, but you display the distance inside the function `d()` so it's displayed.