# Creating a function to act on many variables

Tags: php

php noob here trying to create a function but can't quite find the resource on the web that rids my confusions. Here it goes;

I want to create a function which takes a variable name, for example

Thief's Wit (4)

And converts it to

thiefswit.jpg

So far, here is what I have
**THIS CODE IS LOADED TO TEST MY FUNCTION**

```
require_once 'functions.php';

$mod = "Thief's Wit (4)";
convertImage($mod);
echo $mod;
?>
```

**THIS CODE IS THE ACTUAL FUNCTION**

```
function convertImage($string)
{
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
$string = str_replace("'", "", $string);
$stringlength = strlen($string);
substr ($string, 0, ($stringlength-4));
$string = strtolower ($string);
$string = "$string" . ".jpg";
return $string;
}
?>
```

The format of the strings will always be

NAME HERE (4)

which is why I substr the length-4.

When I run this function, it echoes the original string.

Any help here?
I'm new to PHP and don't really understand

a) What the 'return' does at the end of the function and
b) Does the function inherently know to replace "$string" with the variable you tell it to act on in another file? In this case $mod.

Thanks!

Comment: You're not assigning the return value. (Also you could use a single preg_replace to get rid of all non-letters.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function Echo vs Return](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497848/function-echo-vs-return)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the output of the function:

```
$mod = "Thief's Wit (4)";
$mod = convertImage($mod);  // save the return value to $mod variable
echo $mod;
```

The return value of a function is the value you get from calling a function.  So `convertImage($mod)` will have the value that you return.  At this point, you need to store the results to a variable, which you can do by doing `$mod = convertImage($mod);`

An alternative would be to "pass by reference", where modifying the arguments of your function will modify the variables themselves.

```
function convertImage(&$string) // use &$string to pass by reference
{
  $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
  $string = str_replace("'", "", $string);
  $stringlength = strlen($string);
  substr ($string, 0, ($stringlength-4));
  $string = strtolower ($string);
  $string = "$string" . ".jpg";
  //return $string;  this won't be needed anymore
}

...

$mod = "Thief's Wit (4)";
convertImage($mod);
echo $mod;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to either return the new string you created

```
$mod = convertImage($mod);
```

Or pass by reference, which means that the function `convertImage` is working with the same reference to the passed in string as its caller

```
function convertImage(&$string) {...}
convertImage($mod); // $mod will point to a new string after the call
```

Comment: you can modify them, it's called passing by reference

Comment: @Alfie Yes, and strings are mutable, I was wrong twice. http://phponweb.wordpress.com/2011/02/24/are-php-strings-immutable/

Comment: @Alfie Hey I'll take a downvote with an explanation any day, that's when I learn, on the other hand, downvotes without an explanation really tick me off :)

Comment: @JuanMendes I totally agree - and just so you know, I wasn't the one who downvoted :)

Comment: @Alfie even if it had been, it was deserved

Answer (score 1):

```
function convertImage(&$string) {
$string = strtolower(preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]+/", "", $string));
}
```

should do all you need - it will strip any punctuation and numbers etc, and make it lower case.

edited to allow passing by reference

Comment: sweet, thanks! I also need to substr though, to get rid of the " (4)". This was helpful though!

Comment: this should get rid of that for you too, as " (4)" is made up entirely of non-alpha characters

Answer (score 0):

You aren't assigning the variable value anywhere. To get the actual result, you'd have the function return value to a variable, like so:

```
$mod = convertImage($mod);
```

Once the actual function output is stored in a variable, you'll be able to use it anywhere as you like.

Demo: http://codepad.org/naFB74K6

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    function convertImage(&$string)
    {
        $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);       //Thief'sWit(4)
        $string = str_replace("'", "", $string);            //ThiefsWit(4)
        $string = substr($string, 0, strlen($string)-3);    //ThiefsWit
        $string = strtolower($string);                      //thiefswit
        return $string.".jpg";
    }
    $mod = "Thief's Wit (4)";
    convertImage($mod);
    echo $mod;
?>
```